# Difference between ImageBitmap and ImageData

Tags: javascript, canvas, bitmap

What is the difference between [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) and [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) in JavaScript? when do you want the one or the other?

Comment: read the first paragraph in your links - that's the difference - when you use which is simple ... which one is appropriate

Comment: still don't quite understand it, both are in some form a representation of an image and can both be drawn on a canvas, both is [structural cloneable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) when sending things with postmessage, what is the underlying differences? "which one is appropriate" is an pretty bad answer IMO... i don't work much with canvas - i'm building a own cloneable algoritm with sockets and wonder why i could not pressent them as the same...

Comment: which one of them would be faster to transfer over a web worker for instance? and why do we even have 2 interfaces of what pretty much is the same thing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

An `ImageBitmap` holds a reference to bitmap data, which can be passed to and stored directly in the GPU.

An `ImageData` holds a reference to a [canvas pixel `ArrayBuffer`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#canvas-pixel-arraybuffer), which itself represents raw pixel values as an `Array` of un-premultiplied RGBA color channel values, which is only used by the CPU.

The former can be painted directly by the GPU, with no other operations required. The latter needs to be read (often with alpha pre-multiplication) then moved to the GPU before it can be painted.

They will not take the same amount of time to get copied to the canvas bitmap (a.k.a "painted").

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var ctx = target.getContext("2d");

var imageData = ctx.createImageData(300,150);
var imageBitmap = null;

// fill our ImageData with noise
const data = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = Math.random()*0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
}
// initial draw
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0,0);
// we create our ImageBitmap from the current state
// (=> ~ same bitmap as 'imageData')
createImageBitmap(target).then((bmp)=>{
    imageBitmap = bmp;
  btn.disabled = false;
});


// Benchmark.js playground borrowed from 
// https://jsfiddle.net/533hc71h/

var test1_name = 'ImageData';
function test1()
{
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}
var test2_name = 'ImageBitmap';
function test2()
{
    ctx.drawImage(imageBitmap, 0, 0);
}
function teardown()
{
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,target.width,target.height);
}

var cycleResults = document.getElementById('cycleResults');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// BENCHMARK ====================
btn.onclick = function runTests(){

  btn.setAttribute('disable', true);
    cycleResults.innerHTML = '';
  result.textContent = 'Tests running...';
  
  var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;

  // add tests
  suite
  .add(test1_name || 'test1', test1)
  .add(test2_name || 'test2', test2)
  // add listeners
  .on('cycle', function(event) {
    var result = document.createElement('li');
    result.textContent = String(event.target);
    
    document.getElementById('cycleResults')
        .appendChild(result);
  })
  .on('complete', function() {
    result.textContent = 'Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name');
    btn.setAttribute('disable', false);
    teardown();
  })
  // run async
  .run({ 'async': true });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/1.0.0/benchmark.min.js"></script>

<ul id='cycleResults'>

</ul>
<div id="result">

</div>
<br>
<button id="btn" disabled>
Run Tests
</button><br>

<canvas id="target"></canvas>
```

Running the above snippet I get around 5K OPS (Operations Per Seconds) for drawing the `ImageData`, and 200K+ for the `ImageBitmap` on Chrome (44K vs 125K in FF).

However you can't modify an `ImageBitmap`, nor read its content in any meaningful way.

So,

- If you need to draw a bitmap, use an `ImageBitmap`.
- If you need to read / manipulate the image's data, then use an `ImageData`.

And remember that now we also have means to hold canvas contexts directly in a `Worker` thanks to the [`OffscreenCanvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) API, might suit your needs too.

Comment: Thanks for adding a benchmark! Interestingly, the difference on Firefox 109 is negligible, about 20k ops in both cases.

Comment: @Thomas yes Firefox still hasn't implemented ImageBitmap correctly and they still hold it on the CPU side instead of really creating a GPU bitmap. However on my current machine it still represents a 3x faster path over putImageData, I still wouldn't call it negligible. Maybe your config has something preventing the use of GPU entirely.

Comment: However I must admit a flow in this test: it only computes the time spent on the CPU and not the time spent in the composer, which may be in another thread (e.g it is in Chrome).