# Adding img.crossOrigin = "*" interferes with img.complete

Tags: javascript, image-processing, caching, canvas, observablehq

I have a function that reads map tile images.  I want to keep track of whether or not a certain image has already been cached.  I'm using this function from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15352841/12010984):

```js
function is_cached(src) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;

    return image.complete;
}
```

This was working great.  But then I needed to do some image processing.  In order to copy the image data to a canvas and process it pixel by pixel, I need to use `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage(image, 0, 0)`.  But it bugs me with a cross-origin error.  So I can add a `image.crossOrigin = "*"`, which solves that problem, and I can write to a canvas and do the image processing I need.  That bit looks like this:

```js
  imageOutput.crossOrigin = "*"
  var demCtx;
  imageOutput.onload = function(){
    var c = document.createElement('canvas')
    c.width = c.height = 256
    demCtx = c.getContext('2d')
    demCtx.drawImage(imageOutput, 0, 0)
    var imageData = demCtx.getImageData(0, 0, 256, 256)
  }
```

The issue that arises is that every time I run the larger function which contains these two bits of code, the `is_cached` function returns false every time, except the first time.  But I know that even though `is_cached` is returning false, the images are indeed cached, as they are loading with 0 lag (as opposed to when a novel image is called and it takes a moment to grab it from the server).

**Why might `.crossOrigin = "*"` be interfering with the `.complete` status of an image?**

This is happening within an ObservableHQ notebook.  Might that have something to do with it?  ObservaleHQ gets weird sometimes.

### [ObservableHQ Notebook with the problem](https://observablehq.com/@slutske22/slope-as-a-function-of-latlng-in-leaflet)

You can find this code in the `getTileUrl` cell at the bottom.  This notebook is not yet finished.  You can see the cached status at the `Tile Previously Cached` line after you click around the map of submit changes to the inputs.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: That is_cached function is ran hack. Fetching an image is asynchronous, even when cached. You'd be better just dropping it. Why do you need to know if your images are cached?

Comment: Honest question: Why is it a hack?  The `is_cached` function was a well received answer in the other question, and it gives me the exact / expected behavior I needed, until I introduce the `crossOrigin = "*"` line.  To answer your Q - Short answer: to better understand how the cache works.  Long answer: I want to use the tile images as a data source in an app I'm writing, and I'm trying to find the best method to pre-load tiles and have their data on stand-by for performance purposes.  I'm not sure if the cache will be sufficient, or if I should use another temporary in-browser storage method

Comment: Look at the comments under that answer. It doesn't tell you if an image is cached, but if it has already been loaded by the current document. Also the specs now ask that the fetching os done in a microtask, to not be able to set srcset and crossorigin after without trigerring anything  synchronously. And you may not have enough privilege yet to see it, but this answer has few deserved downvotes too. For what you want, preload all your assets at the beginning of your application, and store ImageBitmaps made from these images, that's the most performant way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.  I had a feeling that relying on the cache may not be the best method of keeping track of my tiles & that I would want to do it manually.  I modified my notebook to save tiles as `ImageBitap`s to an object if they haven't yet been saved.  Then I only need to fetch previously unsaved tiles.  I see how I can use the `ImageBitMap` to write to a canvas and get pixel data from there. Considering I want to access the pixel data later on a pixel by pixel basis, would you say its more performant to save the `ImageBitmaps`, or to save the canvas `ImageData` `Uint8ClampedArray`?

Comment: Saving the ImageData is obviously more performant (getImageData is **really** slow). However, saving all your tiles' ImageData will blow your memory. So th best is probably to get the full ImageData of your current canvas, search for the pixels in this, and only update that ImageData when you do need to perform a new pixel search after the canvas has been updated. Hope you're following, I don't feel I'm very clear...

Comment: As I've been playing around, I tried this both ways.  I turned a 256x256 pixel tile into an ImageBitMap, and the size of the ImageBitMap is 40 *bytes*, at least according to this [sizeof](http://code.iamkate.com/javascript/finding-the-memory-usage-of-objects/) function.  If you then write this ImageBitMap to a canvas with `drawImage`, and pull the pixel data with `getImageData`, the image data is almost 3 megabytes.  How is this possible?  What is happening that an imagebitmap can contain so much data in such a small amout of space?

Comment: ;-) The ImageBitmap object in itself is really small, it only holds its own `width` and `height`, and that's all your `sizeof` measures (and all it can measure). However this object is only the tip of the iceberg we have access to as authors. Under the hood, it is linked to an actual image bitmap that the browser will store in memory. To check this bitmap's size, you need to use the browser's dev tools, or even your OS memory management tools, but a 256*256 bitmap will certainly be higher than 40 bytes ;-)

Comment: The [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap) are pretty weak, but [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031536/difference-between-imagebitmap-and-imagedata) does a good job explaining the difference between `ImageBitMap` and `ImageData`.  Leaving this here for future reference. Thanks Kalido.

Comment: lol I just realized the thread I linked was also answered by you.  Thanks again Kalido!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe fetch api can enforce cache using the param `{cache:"force-cache"}`, however images should be cached as expected. You can fetch the image and pass its blob as an image source.

replace your `imageOutput.src` with

```js
    imageOutput.src = URL.createObjectURL(await fetch(imageUrl, {cache:"force-cache"}).then(r => r.blob()));
```

make your `getTileURL` function `async` as we have to await fetch and blob to be ready to be passed as image source

```js
  async function getTileURL(latArg, lngArg, zoomArg) {
```

Use devtools to inspect network and see tile images coming from disk cache

**edit:**

just try your original code and inspect network via devtools. The tiles images are cache as expected. So no need to hack into fetch blob src.

Comment: With my original code, if I take out the `crossOrigin` line, then when trying to assign a `src` to the image from a URL of an image already in the cache, no new network request is made at all.  New network requests only show up for previously unfetched tiles.  But when I add the `crossOrigin` back in, then every tile request is a new request - the 'size' column gives a real size, not 'from cache'.  But previously fetched images load without lag as if they're coming from the cache.  This is the question - why is the `crossOrigin` affecting the way the browser is caching resources?