# createImageBitmap in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, canvas, bitmap

Is `createImageBitmap` available in node?  The [MDN docs on ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) suggest this is a web-only API.  For some context, I'm using [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) to load an image, and I want to store that image as a bitmap:

```js
import { loadImage } from 'canvas';

const bitmaps = {}

async function saveMyBitmap(imageURL) {

  const image = await loadImage(imageURL);
  const myBitmap = await createImageBitmap(image, 0, 0, 256, 256);
  bitmaps['my-bitmaps-name'] = myBitmap

}
```

Later in the code I need to write this bitmap to a canvas so I can get some pixel data:

```js
import { createCanvas } from 'canvas';

function getDataFromStoredBitmap() {

  const canvas = createCanvas(256, 256);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(bitmaps['my-bitmaps-name'], 0, 0, 256, 256);
  const pixelData = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1); // coords of desired pixel
  // do some more stuff with pixelData

}
```

I would love a way to `createImageBitmap` that works in both browsers *and* nodejs.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: What is it you want to do with the bitmap in nodejs?  Your code shows drawing it to a Canvas, but that's something that only exists in the browser.  There is no drawing or viewing context in nodejs.  If you're just trying to get pixel data from an image, then there are various image processing modules for nodejs that cover that space.

Comment: @jfriend00 they are using node-canvas which brings cairo and the canvas api to node

Comment: I actually don't want to use the bitmap in nodejs, but I want to extend a library that I wrote for the front end to also work for the back end.  Right now that library uses `createImageBitmap`, and I want to leave that option available for use in the browser.  But when I try to include that line and run it in node, I get `createImageBitmap` is undefined.  I'm open to trying other image processing libraries, so long as they work on both front and back end.

Comment: You want only the cropping ability of createImageBitmap? That's not too hard to polyfill. However note that all browsers still don't support ceateImageBitmap.l so your library should already fail on Safari for instance, and if you are using the resizeOptions then it will also fail on  FF

Comment: @Kaiido! I'm using `createImageBitmap` to give the library user the option of storing data with less in-memory-storage taken up.  You may remember [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61691336/adding-img-crossorigin-interferes-with-img-complete).  I don't need this option in node.  But I want to allow that option in the browser, while having my code still run in a node env.  Not sure how to accomplish that, or if I'm misunderstanding the concept of the image bitmap entirely.

Comment: Yes I'm afraid you're not using it correctly here. But for your issue just add a `if( globalThis.createImageBitmap){ ... }`

Comment: Well `createImageBitmap()` doesn't exist in nodejs and doesn't even exist in Safari.  So, you're headed down a blind alley trying to use it in both places.  The only way we could help further would be for you to describe what functionality you actually need and on what platforms.  You will probably need to build your own wrapper around some platform-specific implementations to cover multiple platforms, but without knowing what  the actual functionality requirements are, we can't really help any further.

Comment: If you don't mind, what is wrong with the way I'm using it?  In a browser, I want to store a reference to the image data.  I give the library user the option to configure whether or not the image data is stored as an image bitmap with `createImageBitmap`, or whether or not the the pixel data is extracted as an array and stored as a raw buffer.  The buffer takes up ~3MB of in-memory storage.  The bitmap takes up like 40 bytes (and `getImageData` is called on a pixel-by-pixel basis).  In the node version, I'll never use the bitmap, I just don't want it to break.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your interest.  If you're interested, I'm trying to extend my leaflet plugin [leaflet-topography](https://github.com/slutske22/leaflet-topography) to work in a nodejs application.  I'm currently working to get rid of the requirement that a use supplies a leaflet `L.Map` instance to get it working - that part is done.  But my plugin sort of relies on `createImageBitmap` (not entirely).  The goal is to create a function that returns slope, aspect, and elevation as a function of `latlng` by processing the mapbox rgb tile image data.

Comment: As I told you the last time what you measure here is just the js object size. The actual image data still takes a lot of memory. It can even be allocated to the GPU, making all GPU operations having less memory available there (and more slow cpu to gpu movements), for something that wouldn't be used... For the question's title https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/876 but coincidentally I am writing a monkey patch for browsers, I could look at make it work for node-canvas too.

Comment: I wish there was somewhere where all of this is explained / documented.  Image vs ImageBitmap vs ImageData...So what you're saying is, there is no memory advantage to storing a fetched image using `createImageBitmap` over writing that image to a canvas and calling `getImageData`?  If that's the case, this whole question is moot and I'll just remove that option from my library.  (Coincidentally, I thumbs-upped that question you referenced like 1 hour ago lol)

Comment: Yes there are advantages, moreover against an ImageData. For ImageData vs ImageBitmap you can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033582/3702797 As for memory footprint, ImageBitmap is a clear winner. However, against a compressed image format like you could have through `toBlob()`, it fails lamentably.