# How to get image data from dart:html ImageBitmap?

Tags: dart, html5-canvas

In HTML5 I can get an [ImageBitmap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap)'s data by drawing it on a <canvas> using [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) and then calling [CanvasRenderingContext2D.getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData):

```
function getBitmapData(bitmap) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = bitmap.width;
    canvas.height = bitmap.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
    return canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

I would like to do the same with [dart:html](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-html/dart-html-library.html) but, unlike the HTML5 API, [CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-html/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage.html) does not accept an [ImageBitmap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-html/ImageBitmap-class.html) instance as parameter.

How can I get image data from an instance of dart:html [ImageBitmap](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-html/ImageBitmap-class.html) ?

Comment: Can you provide a JavaScript/html5 code sample which clearly shows what you'd like to achieve?

Comment: @obscure Sure, see my edit.

Comment: You probably already saw https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12379#issuecomment-572239799 But according to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26364 webgl's texImage2d accepts ImageBitmaps, so one solution would be use a webgl context instead of the 2D one (getImageData equivalent is readPixels).

Comment: @Kaiido I hadn't seen that, thanks for the links. I haven't tested it yet but it definitely deserves to be posted as an answer.

Comment: Wait a minute (coming back after 2 years). Your question asks about drawing an **ImageBitmap**, but your code produces an **ImageData**. `drawImage()` doesn't support *ImageData* as input, not even in "vanilla" HTML. Which is it you're trying to use exactly? If the *ImageData*, then use `putImageData`. (But depending on what you're doing you may not even need either of these, if you just want to draw your canvas you can pass `ctx.canvas` as source for `drawImage`. About the difference between ImageData and ImageBitmap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60031536/60033582#60033582