# Fade out tiles in canvas image

Tags: javascript, canvas, fade, tiles

Still learning Canvas. How can I fade out each tile in an image that I have as Image Data in an array:

```
            for (let i = 0; i < tilesY; i++) {
                for (let j = 0; j < tilesX; j++) {
                    this.ctxTile.putImageData(this.tileData[itr], j * tileWidth, i * tileHeight);
                    itr += 1
                }
            }
```

I understand that the solution must have something to do with compositing? I want to fade out each tile individually. The putImageData works and the image is inside canvas, and assembled as a set of tiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd just play with the [`ctx.globalAlpha`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalAlpha) property at the time of drawing to your context to set your tile's alpha. However, [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData) is kind of a strange beast in the API in that it ignores the context transformation, clipping areas and in our case compositing rules, including `globalAlpha`.

So one hack around would be to "erase" the given tile after we've drawn it. For this we can use the [`globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) property that we'll use on a call to a simple `fillRect()` with the inverse `globalAlpha` we want. (Luckily `putImageData` always draws only rectangles).

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const tileWidth  = 50;
const tileHeight = 50;
class Tile {
  constructor(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = Math.round(x); // putImageData only renders at integer coords
    this.y = Math.round(y);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.img = buildImageData(width, height);
    this.alpha = 1;
  }
  isPointInPath(x, y) {
    return x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.width &&
           y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.height;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.putImageData(this.img, this.x, this.y);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1 - this.alpha; // inverse alpha
    // the next drawing will basically erase what it represents
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    // restore the context
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
  }
}
const tiles = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => new Tile(i * tileWidth * 1.25, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight));

canvas.onclick = (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  const clickedTile = tiles.find((tile) => tile.isPointInPath(x, y));
  if (clickedTile) { clickedTile.alpha -= 0.1 };
  redraw();
};
redraw();

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tiles.forEach((tile) => tile.draw());
}
function buildImageData(width, height) {
  const img = new ImageData(width, height);
  const arr = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
  }
  return img;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on each tile to lower its alpha.</p>
<canvas></canvas>
```

However this means that for each tile we have one `putImageData` + one composited `fillRect`. If you've got a lot of tiles, that makes for a pretty big overhead.

So instead the best might be to convert all your *ImageData* objects to *ImageBitmap* ones. To understand the difference between both I invite you to read [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60033582/3702797).

Once we have ImageBitmaps, we can apply the `globalAlpha` on our draw call directly:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const tileWidth  = 50;
const tileHeight = 50;
class Tile {
  constructor(x, y, width, height) {
    this.x = Math.round(x); // putImageData only renders at integer coords
    this.y = Math.round(y);
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.alpha = 1;
    const imgData = buildImageData(width, height);
    // createImageBitmap is "async"
    this.ready = createImageBitmap(imgData)
      .then((bmp) => this.img = bmp);
  }
  isPointInPath(x, y) {
    return x >= this.x && x <= this.x + this.width &&
           y >= this.y && y <= this.y + this.height;
  }
  draw() {
    // single draw per tile
    ctx.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
    ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
  }
}
const tiles = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, i) => new Tile(i * tileWidth * 1.25, 0, tileWidth, tileHeight));

canvas.onclick = (e) => {
  const x = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
  const clickedTile = tiles.find((tile) => tile.isPointInPath(x, y));
  if (clickedTile) { clickedTile.alpha -= 0.1 };
  redraw();
};
// wait for all the ImageBitmaps are generated
Promise.all(tiles.map((tile) => tile.ready)).then(redraw);

function redraw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  tiles.forEach((tile) => tile.draw());
}
function buildImageData(width, height) {
  const img = new ImageData(width, height);
  const arr = new Uint32Array(img.data.buffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
  }
  return img;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on each tile to lower its alpha.</p>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: This is an eye opener for me. Thanks for providing such an excellent and detailed answer; I will go down the Bitmap route as it provides what I need.